# Stop native dialer application after receiving intent in broadcast receiver of my app

Tags: android

I have broadcast receiver to receive intent for new outgoing call as

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

i am getting intent in my receiver from that i open my application to call same phone number up to this all works fine but native dialer app pops up on my application so i want to close native dialer app after opening my activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this post: http://android-developers.blogspot.hu/2013/05/handling-phone-call-requests-right-way.html

You will probably need to "setResultData(null);" to tell the system you handled this.
(haven't try)